# QGIS freezes using MMQGIS plugin

Tags: qgis, geocoding, mmqgis

I have a problem with geocoding addresses (about one thousand). I have a file (.csv) with a large number of addresses: street, house number, ZIP code, city. I used the mmqgis plug, but after geocoding start QGIS freezes. Does anyone has similar problem? Should I use another tool?

QGIS version 2.14, operating system Windows 10,

There are no errors, only QGIS freezes. I did this before with another data (diffrent numbers) and everything was ok.

Now it works for few addresses and it freezes, or not at all.

Comment: What is a large number? One person's 100 thousand is another person's trillion. What version of QGIS? What OS? Any error messages?

Comment: What happens if you run it with the exact same dataset but first extract 10, 100 or 1000 addresses?

Comment: @RichardLaw - Yes, it's helpful, first I did 700 addresses, then rest.

Comment: Usually when I run this tool QGIS freezes... nothing wrong, it's still cranking away in the background. Then when its done, everything comes back to life, result is in the map. If you have 1000 addresses it might take quite a while and seem to be frozen forever, but it's likely still running in the background...